# ASP.NET application does not work on CentOs 7 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, centos, webmin

I am able to publish asp.net in vps running on CentOs 7 server.

However, when i try to launch it it just gives me the code of `.aspx` file that I am trying to access

**What i have tried so far:**

- Reinstalled .net 3.0 .
- Change permissions of folder .
- Moving to different virtual server.

Comment: thats what i see when opening a apsx file :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzXbL.jpg

Comment: Seems like the file type is not handled. The file is delivered as is. Your webserver configuration must me changed to make it work.

Comment: Non-.NET Core applications are not fully supported to run on Linux. Please migrate first.